# replace value with condition

Tags: r, simulation

I want to replace more than one values if that values satisfy a condition
this is the code that I used

```
set.seed(2001)
x <- rnorm(15, 1, 3)
mu <- mean(x)
h= -2.456
C.CUSUM <- function(x) {
  c <- numeric(length(x))
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    c[i] <- min(0, c[i-1] + x[i-1] - mu)
  }
  c
  }
  C.CUSUM(x)
```

After running C.CUSUM function, I want to write this line in R

if c[i] > h then k=i, for instance if c[3] > h and c[4] > h then k = 3, 4

Comment: I think this OT here. Also, what is `k` and what is your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
c <- C.CUSUM(x)
# calling the function to store a vector of values in c
c.test <- ifelse (c > h, 1, 0)
# creates a new vector and assigns 1 to values that are above h, 0 to the rest
k.test <- which(c.test==1)
# creates a vector of the position numbers from c.test where c.test is 1
```